# Cannot read property 'replace' of null when turning a string value into Number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, replace

Hey im trying to convert a string that holds numbers but the string has commas in it and I'm trying to remove those commas as well.

```js
let why = "42,343,324"
console.log(typeof why) // string
let noCommas = parseFloat(why.replace(/,/g, ''));
console.log(noCommas) // 42343324
```

but when I replace **why** value with a prop value, it gives me an error saying **Cannot read property 'replace' of null**

```
let why = visitsPerPerson
console.log(typeof why)
let noCommas = parseFloat(why.replace(/,/g, ''));
console.log(noCommas)
```

`Output: Cannot read property 'replace' of null`

The prop is a string value that holds numbers returned from an API
the prop itself doesn't return null but returns a string with numbers in it and can verify when I console log:
`console.log(visitsPerPerson)`

Comment: Please share the response of your API.

Comment: I would guess it's because at the time you're trying to render that information the data hasn't been returned from the API so the variable is undefined. API requests are asynchronous, and you should be using React state if you're not already doing so.

Comment: Maybe it's not the same time when you verify it has value and when you'd need it to. What happens if you put `console.log(visitsPerPerson)` immediately before or after the `why = ` assignment? How do you obtain the value from the API response?

Comment: @Andy Im already using useState and useEffect to get the value of the prop **visitsPerPerson**, so I would have to use useState and useEffect again to do the calculations?

Comment: @marekful ahh ok, this seems to be a deeper issue. When I remove everything and just console.log(typeof visitesPerMill, visitesPerMill), I get back four responses
**object null**,
**string 5,550** ,
**string 5,550**,
**string 5,550**,

Comment: You should update your question with a [mcve]. We didn't know you were using `useState` or `useEffect` because your question doesn't mention it, and we can't debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

I re-produced the second code snippet and got expected output:

`NaN` (Not a Number), which is correct and the expected result for "visitsPerPerson".

Did I understand something wrong?

```js
let why = "visitsPerPerson";
console.log(typeof why); // string
let noCommas = parseFloat(why.replace(/,/g, ''));
console.log(noCommas); // NaN (Not a Number, which is correct)
```

Comment: **visitsPerPerson** isnt a string itself. It's a prop in react which holds a value. For example, **visitsPerPerson** can hold "56,798" which I get from api

Comment: I see; when porting to JS, shouldn't it be handled as a variable then, like `let why = visitsPerPerson` ? (sorry, I am not that familiar with react). Because with quotes JS defenitely takes it as a string - just wondering.